# Alertmanager failing due to "unmarshal errors: line 19: field matchers not found in type config.plain"

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to add custom alert-routing config to my alertmanager, deployed as a part of kube-prometheus-stack. But prometheus-operator pod, while trying to generate the alertmanager configmap, fails due to the following error:

```
level=error ts=2021-05-31T06:29:38.883470881Z caller=klog.go:96 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="Sync \"infra-services/prometheus-operator-kube-p-alertmanager\" failed: provision alertmanager configuration: base config from Secret could not be parsed: yaml: unmarshal errors:\n line 19: field matchers not found in type config.plain"
```

I also validated the same using amtool inside alertmanager container, which gives the same error. Here is my alertmanager.yml file:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
  slack_api_url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzzzzzzzz
receivers:
- name: slack-notifications
  slack_configs:
  - channel: '#alerts'
    send_resolved: true
    text: '{{ template "slack.myorg.text" . }}'
- name: blackhole-receiver
route:
  group_by:
  - alertname
  group_interval: 5m
  group_wait: 30s
  receiver: blackhole-receiver
  repeat_interval: 12h
  routes:
  - matchers:
    - severity=~"warning|critical"
    receiver: slack-notifications
templates:
- /etc/alertmanager/config/*.tmpl
```

I have followed https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/ and https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/master/doc/examples/simple.yml to write my simple alertmanager config.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to change from:

```
  routes:
  - matchers:
    - severity=~"warning|critical"
    receiver: slack-notifications
```

To:

```
  routes:
    - match_re:
        severity: "warning|critical"
      receiver: slack-notifications
```

Comment: This definitely solved the issue for me instantly. But I found that "match_re" is deprecated as per https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route . Is it safe to use it, as future versions of alertmanager might remove the field?  Also, any idea why is "matchers" is not allowed, or what's wrong with the previous configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to (at least) `quay.io/prometheus/alertmanager:v0.22.2`, and it'll work.

It would be best if you didn't continue using `match_re` since it's deprecated.